# Does Flink automatically checkpoint AggregateFunction's state and how to use AggregatingStateDescriptor?

Tags: apache-flink

I am implementing a `AggregateFunction` to measure the duration between two events after `.window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(gap))`
. After the second event is processed, the window is closed.

Will flink automatically checkpoint the state of the `AggregateFunction` so that existing data in the accumulator is not lost from restarting?

Since I am not sure about that. I tried to implement `AggregatingState` in a `RichAggregateFunction`:
`class MyAgg extends RichAggregateFunction<IN, ACC, OUT>`

`AggregatingState` requires `AggregatingStateDescriptor`. Its constructor has this signature:

```
            String name,
            AggregateFunction<IN, ACC, OUT> aggFunction,
            Class<ACC> stateType) {
```

I am very confused by the `aggFunction`. What should be put here? Isn't it the `MyAgg` that I am trying to define in the first place?

Comment: In what context are you using this AggregateFunction? Is this on a streaming window, or somewhere else?

Comment: @davidanderson
it is a streaming window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AggregateFunction` doesn't have any state. But the aggregating state used in a streaming window (and manipulated by an `AggregateFunction`) is checkpointed as part of the window's state.

A `RichAggregateFunction` cannot be used in a window context, and an `AggregateFunction` cannot have its own state. It's designed this way because if an `AggregateFunction` were allowed to use a state descriptor to define `ValueState`, for example, then that state wouldn't be mergeable -- and to keep the Window API reasonably clean, all window state needs to be mergeable (for the sake of session windows).

`AggregatingState` is something you might use in a `KeyedProcessFunction`, for example. In that context, you need to define how elements are to be aggregated into the accumulator (i.e., the `AggregatingState`), which you do with an `AggregateFunction`.